# How to make IIWA mobile?

Tags: python, drake

We are building [a simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhPYu.jpg) for a robot that will traverse a grocery shop to collect necessary items from the shelves for online deliveries. To do this, **we need to make the IIWA robot mobile rather than welded on the ground.** **We are looking for a way to make the robot move on a two-dimensional plane (the ground), so it can move between shelves to collect items.** We have been following Russ' MIT lecture videos and reading his notes, however thus far we have been unable to find an appropriate resource for this task. We'd appreciate it if you could point us in the right direction, thank you.

Currently, the robot is stationary with a few shelves around it. We aim to make the robot mobile to simulate a realistic grocery shop environment, and **we require some help getting the robot to move on a two-dimensional plane.**

**Essentially, what I'm asking is how to implement a mobile base for the IIWA robot in the simulation with Drake.**

Comment: I have edited the post, hope it is more clear now. In a nutshell, I am looking for a way to make the robot move on the ground rather than being stationary.

Comment: What kind of dofs to you want for the moving base?  Just three x-y-yaw?  Or also roll / pitch?  You can use some combination of prismatic joint / revolute joint / planar joint to get what you want.  Add joint(s) between a fixed point on the world (e.g. origin) and the iiwa.

Comment: We require x-y-yaw at the moment. Can you give some suggestions on what kind of a joint combination would we need to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as adding a [PlanarJoint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_planar_joint.html) between your robot and the world.  If you are using urdf, it could be as simple as e.g.

```
  <joint name="mobile_base" type="planar">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
  </joint>
```

(but do note that some of the iiwa urdf models have an extra `base` link inserted).

Comment: How would it be possible to implement the mobile base for [this](https://github.com/RussTedrake/drake/blob/master/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/iiwa7/iiwa7_no_collision.sdf) sdf model? We are using the iiwa7 with no collision model from the Drake repository.

Comment: I have been trying to utilize the AddJoint method to add a PlanarJoint to the model I mentioned above but I've been unsuccesful so far.  

Here's what I've tried:  

`bottom = plant.GetBodyByName("iiwa_link_0")  

mobile_base = plant.AddJoint(PlanarJoint(name="mobile_base",
 
frame_on_parent=plant.world_frame(), frame_on_child=bottom.body_frame()))`  

I get this error: "Failure at systems/controllers/inverse_dynamics_controller.cc:39 in SetUp(): condition 'num_positions == dim' failed."

Comment: it looks like you are successfully adding the joint to the plant, but now your controller has more degrees of freedom and you haven't updated it (for instance, you might be sending the wrong number of gains).